# CodeIgniter - Functions with and without arguments

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, arguments

I have a function in CodeIgniter which populates a list of days. I called it init_days(). I call this function using ajax and output the returned values into a div using jQuery.
This function does not take any arguments; I load the default values in from a model and work from there. (This function loads a couple of days into a list, starting from the current day (today). I load the current day/month/year/.. in from my model).

However, since this list will have to be manipulated (to show, for example, the next month). In this case, I suppose I'd have to pass arguments to my function.

Now, I don't really want to have one function to initiate the list (init_days()), and then another function, lets call it populate_days(), which takes arguments but essentially does the same thing, just with manipulated values.

Is there a way to check whether or not I'm passing values to my function? That way I could just keep my function the way it is and add a check for arguments. Or perhaps I'm making this more difficult than it is (as usual :( ) and there's an easier way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As always, seeing some could will help, can you take the time to post it? You are familiar with your code, but we are not. You may want to look at setting default arguments to your function, but it's hard to tell exactly what you're after.

Comment: @Madmartigan, sorry. I should've added it. The answer by JohnP solved my question though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a set amount of arguments, you could just give them default values

```
function init_days($start = '', $end = '') {
   if (!empty($start) && !empty($end)) {  
     //got both vars. do something with it here
   }
}
```

You could also use `func_get_arg()` if you're working with variable numbers of parameters. So your method will work with or without arguments

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

Comment: Thanks. I have a set number of arguments so the code you provided is exactly what I was looking for. Should've thought of doing it that way, haha. Thank you, sir!